# Why is the parallelized version slower than the single-thread version. False sharing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, process

So here is two versions of a code:

```
class VectorCount {
private:
     char               *arr;int                
     size;unsigned long long count;
public:
     VectorCount(char *arr, unsigned int size, unsigned long long count) : arr(arr), size(size), count(count) {}

     void add() {
          while(count--) {
               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                         arr[i]++;
               }
          }
     }
};

// Single-thread version of the code
void main_st() {
     // initizalize array
     char arr[10];

     // create object
     VectorCount v(arr, 10, 100000000);

     // run add
     v.add();
}

// Parallelized version of the code
void main_mt() {
     // initialize array
     char arrA[10];
     char arrB[10];

     // create objects
     VectorCount v1(arrA, 10, 50000000);
     VectorCount v2(arrB, 10, 50000000);

     // create threads
     thread t1, t2;
     t1.create_thread(v1, v1.add);
     t2.create_thread(v2, v2.add);

     // join threads
     t1.join();
     t2.join();

     // Code to do the final sum of the two VectorCount objects to get the same
     // result as the single-threaded version (assume negligible overhead here)
}
```

Lets say the program creates a single instance of **VectorCount** object with array size of 10 and a count of 100 million. The single thread version takes 5 seconds to complete the sum. The parallelized version uses two threads, each holding a separate instance of **VectorCount** with an array size of 10, and so each **VectorCount** instance is given a count of just 50 million since each thread does half the work. The parallelized version takes 8 seconds to complete. Why is it slower? I was thinking this is due to false sharing. But I'm not sure. Cache size is 64 bytes.

Can we make the parallelized version run faster? I was thinking of changing the **VectorCount** array size. But what size would make the parallelized version run faster using 2 threads? Since cache size is 64 bytes, int is 4 bytes, then would size = 16 solve false sharing in this case? (4 x 16 = 64).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It would be nice to have a reproducible example. Better even make use of https://quick-bench.com

Comment: there are some possibility:
first is that it may both thread schedule on same core which is slower than single threaded.
second is that maybe two threaded version each time schedule on different core which in result flush cache in older core and miss cache in current core.

Comment: Your code does very little and is likely optimised away by the compiler, creating the threads probably takes longer than the 10 assignments that your code probably boils down to, if your code isn't optimised any performance measurements are meaningless

Comment: Are `t1` and `t2` `std::thread`s? I can't seem to find any member functions called `create_thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does very little work, with enough context the optimiser can turn your code into basically (assuming, as in your case, `count` is divisible by `size`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  arr[i] = count / size;
}
```

As the values of `arr` are never used the optimiser can even eliminate this code.

Note that as `arr` is not initialised your code has undefined behaviour. You should use `char arr[10] {0}` to initialise the array to `0`.

However the more complex you make the optimiser's job the less likely it is to be able to spot these opportunities. Passing your arrays and parameters through the machinery of the `std::thread` constructors likely prevents the optimiser realising it can optimise your code in this way. Rearranging your code to:

```
std::thread t1([] {
    char arrA[10]{0};
    VectorCount v1(arrA, 10, 50'000'000);
    v1.add();
    });
std::thread t2([] {
    char arrA[10]{0};
    VectorCount v1(arrA, 10, 50'000'000);
    v1.add();
    }
);
```

makes it more similar to your single threaded version and the optimiser is able to perform its magic and the parallel version is much faster: https://godbolt.org/z/9j9ocoMTd. If you look in the assembly code for the first version you'll notice there is mention of `50000000` but not `100000000`, in the second version you'll notice `50000000` isn't there either as both versions optimise away to nothing.

Note that it is still slower than the single threaded version but as the single threaded version only takes ~100ns the overhead of creating and joining 2 threads is likely more than the saving from parallelism.

On my machine with visual studio this code takes 85ms for the single threaded version and 45ms for the parallel version (visual studio doesn't manage to completely remove your code).

Blocking the optimiser gives more similar results on GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/Mhf5xjx33